# Вывести числа из таблицы с их словесной расшифровкой

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, запрос, plsql

Дана таблица: 
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900

```
insert into table(n,t) values (0,'');
insert into table(n,t) values (1,'один');
insert into table(n,t) values (10,'десять');
insert into table(n,t) values (100,'сто');
```

Сейчас выводятся все числа от 0 до 999:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT distinct a.n + b.n + c.n r
FROM table a, table b, table c
WHERE a.n >= b.n OR b.n <= c.n ORDER BY r) A
WHERE A.r < 1000;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как к ним можно дописать письменную расшифровку ?

Comment: так и все остальное вставляйте

Comment: Если  припишу словесную расшифровку, то DISTINCT уже работать не будет, следовательно будут повторения или у Вас другая мысль?

Comment: а вы сразу выбирайте, чтобы в `a` были только сотник, в `b` только десятки, и в `a`  единицы, тогда и дистинкт не нужен, и слова можно подвязать.

Comment: `SELECT A.n + B.n, B.t || ' ' || A.t FROM ( 
SELECT * 
FROM dtstr
WHERE LENGTH(n) = 1) A,
( 
SELECT  * 
FROM dtstr
WHERE LENGTH(n) = 2) B;` Здесь у меня все равно есть повторения, к примеру есть 23 - двадцать три и 23 - пятнадцать восемь

Comment: `... SELECT distinct a.n + b.n + c.n r, a.t  ...`

Comment: все равно повторения идут

Comment: Почему в sql? Есть возможность написать функцию?